# Android datepicker get date and time

Tags: android, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I am using datepicker for reserving a table in a restaurant

I have to use two date pickers, one to get date and one to get time

but its not user friendly
i want to use both of them in the same time

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    final int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    final int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    final int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    final int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    final int minute1 = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    final Calendar v = Calendar.getInstance();
    final int year2 = v.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    final int month2 = v.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    final int day2 = v.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    final int hour2 = v.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    final int minute2 = v.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    final String date;
    final EditText rt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.f1);
    final EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.e1);
    et1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DatePickerDialog datepick = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

                }
            } ,year,month,day);
            datepick.setTitle("select date");
            datepick.show();
        }
    rt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TimePickerDialog timepick = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {


                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    rt1.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);


                }
            }, hour, minute1, true
            );
            timepick.setTitle("select time");
            timepick.show();


        }
    });

}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android doesn't have anything built-in to do this, you can create your own date and time picker. Below is the code to do it:

**date_time_picker_dialog.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:padding="8dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/date_picker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:calendarViewShown="true"
    android:spinnersShown="false"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />

<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/time_picker"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/date_time_ok"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="OK"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In your **java code** use the following code:

```
final View dialogView = View.inflate(activity, R.layout.date_time_picker_dialog, null);
final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).create();

dialogView.findViewById(R.id.date_time_ok).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

     DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
     TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.time_picker);

     Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(datePicker.getYear(),
                        datePicker.getMonth(),
                        datePicker.getDayOfMonth(),
                        timePicker.getCurrentHour(),
                        timePicker.getCurrentMinute());

     time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
     alertDialog.dismiss();
}});
alertDialog.setView(dialogView);
alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no build-in Picker that can do this.

But have a look at the [SublimePicker](https://github.com/vikramkakkar/SublimePicker) on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Show the time picker on the date picker call back

```
et1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DatePickerDialog datepick = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

                // Date results here

                TimePickerDialog timepick = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

                        // Time results here

                    }
                }, hour, minute1, true);
                timepick.setTitle("select time");
                timepick.show();
            }
        } ,year,month,day);
        datepick.setTitle("select date");
        datepick.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't appear the date and the time

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to get/set date and time in one custom dialog :

CustomDateTimePicker.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created by admin on 6/29/2016.
 */
public class CustomDateTimePicker implements View.OnClickListener {
    private DatePicker datePicker;
    private TimePicker timePicker;
    private ViewSwitcher viewSwitcher;

    private final int SET_DATE = 100, SET_TIME = 101, SET = 102, CANCEL = 103;

    private Button btn_setDate, btn_setTime, btn_set, btn_cancel;

    private Calendar calendar_date = null;

    private Activity activity;

    private ICustomDateTimeListener iCustomDateTimeListener = null;

    private Dialog dialog;

    private boolean is24HourView = true, isAutoDismiss = true;

    private int selectedHour, selectedMinute;

    public CustomDateTimePicker(Activity a,
                                ICustomDateTimeListener customDateTimeListener) {
        activity = a;
        iCustomDateTimeListener = customDateTimeListener;

        dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                resetData();
            }
        });

        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        View dialogView = getDateTimePickerLayout();
        dialog.setContentView(dialogView);
    }

    public View getDateTimePickerLayout() {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams linear_match_wrap = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams linear_wrap_wrap = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams frame_match_wrap = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams button_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);

        LinearLayout linear_main = new LinearLayout(activity);
        linear_main.setLayoutParams(linear_match_wrap);
        linear_main.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linear_main.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        LinearLayout linear_child = new LinearLayout(activity);
        linear_child.setLayoutParams(linear_wrap_wrap);
        linear_child.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        LinearLayout linear_top = new LinearLayout(activity);
        linear_top.setLayoutParams(linear_match_wrap);

        btn_setDate = new Button(activity);
        btn_setDate.setLayoutParams(button_params);
        btn_setDate.setText("Set Date");
        btn_setDate.setId(SET_DATE);
        btn_setDate.setOnClickListener(this);

        btn_setTime = new Button(activity);
        btn_setTime.setLayoutParams(button_params);
        btn_setTime.setText("Set Time");
        btn_setTime.setId(SET_TIME);
        btn_setTime.setOnClickListener(this);

        linear_top.addView(btn_setDate);
        linear_top.addView(btn_setTime);

        viewSwitcher = new ViewSwitcher(activity);
        viewSwitcher.setLayoutParams(frame_match_wrap);

        datePicker = new DatePicker(activity);
        timePicker = new TimePicker(activity);
        timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                selectedHour = hourOfDay;
                selectedMinute = minute;
            }
        });

        viewSwitcher.addView(timePicker);
        viewSwitcher.addView(datePicker);

        LinearLayout linear_bottom = new LinearLayout(activity);
        linear_match_wrap.topMargin = 8;
        linear_bottom.setLayoutParams(linear_match_wrap);

        btn_set = new Button(activity);
        btn_set.setLayoutParams(button_params);
        btn_set.setText("Set");
        btn_set.setId(SET);
        btn_set.setOnClickListener(this);

        btn_cancel = new Button(activity);
        btn_cancel.setLayoutParams(button_params);
        btn_cancel.setText("Cancel");
        btn_cancel.setId(CANCEL);
        btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(this);

        linear_bottom.addView(btn_set);
        linear_bottom.addView(btn_cancel);

        linear_child.addView(linear_top);
        linear_child.addView(viewSwitcher);
        linear_child.addView(linear_bottom);

        linear_main.addView(linear_child);

        return linear_main;
    }

    public void showDialog() {
        if (!dialog.isShowing()) {
            if (calendar_date == null)
                calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();

            selectedHour = calendar_date.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            selectedMinute = calendar_date.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            timePicker.setIs24HourView(is24HourView);
            timePicker.setCurrentHour(selectedHour);
            timePicker.setCurrentMinute(selectedMinute);

            datePicker.updateDate(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    calendar_date.get(Calendar.DATE));

            dialog.show();

            btn_setDate.performClick();
        }
    }

    public void setAutoDismiss(boolean isAutoDismiss) {
        this.isAutoDismiss = isAutoDismiss;
    }

    public void dismissDialog() {
        if (!dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.dismiss();
    }

    public void setDate(Calendar calendar) {
        if (calendar != null)
            calendar_date = calendar;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        if (date != null) {
            calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar_date.setTime(date);
        }
    }

    public void setDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        if (month < 12 && month >= 0 && day < 32 && day >= 0 && year > 100
                && year < 3000) {
            calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar_date.set(year, month, day);
        }

    }

    public void setTimeIn24HourFormat(int hourIn24Format, int minute) {
        if (hourIn24Format < 24 && hourIn24Format >= 0 && minute >= 0
                && minute < 60) {
            if (calendar_date == null)
                calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar_date.set(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    calendar_date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), hourIn24Format,
                    minute);

            is24HourView = true;
        }
    }

    public void setTimeIn12HourFormat(int hourIn12Format, int minute,
                                      boolean isAM) {
        if (hourIn12Format < 13 && hourIn12Format > 0 && minute >= 0
                && minute < 60) {
            if (hourIn12Format == 12)
                hourIn12Format = 0;

            int hourIn24Format = hourIn12Format;

            if (!isAM)
                hourIn24Format += 12;

            if (calendar_date == null)
                calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar_date.set(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    calendar_date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), hourIn24Format,
                    minute);

            is24HourView = false;
        }
    }

    public void set24HourFormat(boolean is24HourFormat) {
        is24HourView = is24HourFormat;
    }

    public interface ICustomDateTimeListener {
        public void onSet(Dialog dialog, Calendar calendarSelected,
                          Date dateSelected, int year, String monthFullName,
                          String monthShortName, int monthNumber, int date,
                          String weekDayFullName, String weekDayShortName, int hour24,
                          int hour12, int min, int sec, String AM_PM);

        public void onCancel();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case SET_DATE:
                btn_setTime.setEnabled(true);
                btn_setDate.setEnabled(false);
                viewSwitcher.showNext();
                break;

            case SET_TIME:
                btn_setTime.setEnabled(false);
                btn_setDate.setEnabled(true);
                viewSwitcher.showPrevious();
                break;

            case SET:
                if (iCustomDateTimeListener != null) {
                    int month = datePicker.getMonth();
                    int year = datePicker.getYear();
                    int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();


                    calendar_date.set(year, month, day, selectedHour,
                            selectedMinute);

                    iCustomDateTimeListener.onSet(dialog, calendar_date,
                            calendar_date.getTime(), calendar_date
                                    .get(Calendar.YEAR),
                            getMonthFullName(calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH)),
                            getMonthShortName(calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH)),
                            calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar_date
                                    .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                            getWeekDayFullName(calendar_date
                                    .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)),
                            getWeekDayShortName(calendar_date
                                    .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)), calendar_date
                                    .get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                            getHourIn12Format(calendar_date
                                    .get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)), calendar_date
                                    .get(Calendar.MINUTE), calendar_date
                                    .get(Calendar.SECOND), getAMPM(calendar_date));
                }
                if (dialog.isShowing() && isAutoDismiss)
                    dialog.dismiss();
                break;

            case CANCEL:
                if (iCustomDateTimeListener != null)
                    iCustomDateTimeListener.onCancel();
                if (dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param date
     *            date in String
     * @param fromFormat
     *            format of your <b>date</b> eg: if your date is 2011-07-07
     *            09:09:09 then your format will be <b>yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss</b>
     * @param toFormat
     *            format to which you want to convert your <b>date</b> eg: if
     *            required format is 31 July 2011 then the toFormat should be
     *            <b>d MMMM yyyy</b>
     * @return formatted date
     */
    public static String convertDate(String date, String fromFormat,
                                     String toFormat) {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(fromFormat);
            Date d = simpleDateFormat.parse(date);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(d);

            simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(toFormat);
            simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
            date = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return date;
    }

    private String getMonthFullName(int monthNumber) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthNumber);

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
        simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
        String monthName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

        return monthName;
    }

    private String getMonthShortName(int monthNumber) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthNumber);

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
        simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
        String monthName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

        return monthName;
    }

    private String getWeekDayFullName(int weekDayNumber) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, weekDayNumber);

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
        simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
        String weekName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

        return weekName;
    }

    private String getWeekDayShortName(int weekDayNumber) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, weekDayNumber);

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EE");
        simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
        String weekName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

        return weekName;
    }

    private int getHourIn12Format(int hour24) {
        int hourIn12Format = 0;

        if (hour24 == 0)
            hourIn12Format = 12;
        else if (hour24 <= 12)
            hourIn12Format = hour24;
        else
            hourIn12Format = hour24 - 12;

        return hourIn12Format;
    }

    private String getAMPM(Calendar calendar) {
        String ampm = (calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == (Calendar.AM)) ? "AM"
                : "PM";
        return ampm;
    }

    private void resetData() {
        calendar_date = null;
        is24HourView = true;
    }

    public static String pad(int integerToPad) {
        if (integerToPad >= 10 || integerToPad < 0)
            return String.valueOf(integerToPad);
        else
            return "0" + String.valueOf(integerToPad);
    }
}
```

In your Activity :

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

     CustomDateTimePicker custom;
Button btnEventDateTime;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    btnEventDateTime = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEventDateTime));
    custom = new CustomDateTimePicker(this,
                    new CustomDateTimePicker.ICustomDateTimeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onSet(Dialog dialog, Calendar calendarSelected,
                                          Date dateSelected, int year, String monthFullName,
                                          String monthShortName, int monthNumber, int date,
                                          String weekDayFullName, String weekDayShortName,
                                          int hour24, int hour12, int min, int sec,
                                          String AM_PM) {
    //                        ((TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.edtEventDateTime))
                            edtEventDateTime.setText("");
                            edtEventDateTime.setText(year
                                    + "-" + (monthNumber + 1) + "-" + calendarSelected.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                                    + " " + hour24 + ":" + min
                                    + ":" + sec);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {

                        }
                    });
            /**
             * Pass Directly current time format it will return AM and PM if you set
             * false
             */
            custom.set24HourFormat(true);
            /**
             * Pass Directly current data and time to show when it pop up
             */
            custom.setDate(Calendar.getInstance());
            btnEventDateTime.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            custom.showDialog();
                        }
                    });
    }
    }
```